# Python error while attempting to call cocos from the command line

Tags: python, cocos2d-x-3.x

To be clear, this is not an issue about creating a new project. I have a sneaking suspicion that it may have something to do with my initial setup using setup.py.

**The Problem:**

Calling "cocos" from the command line generates the following error:

```
*C:\Users\pixelhacker>cocos
File "C:\cocos2d-x-3.12\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\/cocos.py", line 198
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax*
```

**Additional Info:**
During the setup process the only issue I had was setting up the ANT_SDK. In order to get that part of the setup to work I created a environment variable that included the root folder \bin.

**Environment Info:**

**Cocos Version:** cocos2d-x-3.12

**NDK Version:** android-ndk-r12b

**Android SDK Version:** Installed back on 5/5/2016

**Ant Version:** apache-ant-1.9.7

**Operating System:** Windows 8.1 x64

If I've missed anything let me know. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I was running an older version of Python, version 2.5. I upgraded to the latest version but the issue persisted. After some research, I decided to use version 2.7.

Problem resolved.